# The function Release is not compiled into DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I'm writing a DLL in Visual C++. Why not compile a function, which I call Release, inside a DLL?

> Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Release
>   C:\projects...\my.def

If I replace the Release function to Release1, then it works.

my.h

```
DLL_API void Release();
```

my.cpp

```
void Release() {

}
```

my.def

```
LIBRARY   "myDll"
EXPORTS
    Release   @1
```

Comment: If you don't show you magical code, I would say the wizards around here will not be able to do their magic on it

Comment: It is not a "forbidden" function name.  Crystal ball says that you have a .h file somewhere with a macro that renames it to something else.  Use the compiler's /P option to look at the preprocessed file so you'll have a better idea what that macro looks like.

Comment: FrankS101, edited question